# Function defined on a zero measured set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-sets

I am trying to show that a function on a zero measured set is measurable 
My basic idea is that because i know every zero measured set is lebesgue measurable then i have to show every function with a measurable domain is measurable 
I dunno if i am right or wrong 
Please help me solve it ! 
Thanks

Comment: Just read again what a measurable function is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Every subset of a Lebesgue-measurable set of measure zero is Lebesgue-measurable (with measure zero).

Answer (score 0):

Proposition (2) page 55 in Royden Real Analysis:
Let the function  *f* be defined on a measurable set *E* . Then *f* is measurable if and only if for each open set $O$ , the inverse image of $O$ under *f* ,
*$f^{-1}$*($O$)={$x \in $ *E*| $f (x) \in O$} is measurable .
Now, since *$f^{-1}$*($O$) $\subseteq$ $E$ $\forall$ open set $O$ and  *m*($E$)=0 ,but any subset of a set of measure zero is measurable so *$f^{-1}$*($O$) is measuable $\square$